# Foreach in not iterating through values

Tags: c#, database, function, rest, foreach

I am developing an application where I have to perform some update operation on  each machine in the database. Every machine has a unique Id. Then there is also an area code under which several machines come. Area codes are also unique. I am reading these ids from the database and storing them in a list and then I want to hit the API one by one using these Ids. The API will give me a response which I have to read and update the database accordingly . I am using foreach but I don't know what mistake I am doing that it is not iterating to the second element(second id) of the list and I am not able to call the function with the 2nd Id to hit the API.

```
public static void ProcessIds(string areacode1, string areacode2)
{
    // this is working fine I am getting correct values
    List<IntermediateAPIRequest.IntermediateIds> Ids = 
                                              GetIntermediateIDList(areacode1, areacode2); 
    
    APIRequest apiRequest = new APIRequest();
    foreach (IntermediateAPIRequest.IntermediateIds id in Ids)
    {

       //code for creating API request--this now fetches the 1st Id from
       // the list and creates the request

        APIresponse result = GetAPIResponsePerID(URL, id.machineID, apiRequest);

        //Code for dealing with the response, for the time being I am 
        // simply displaying it onto the console. 
     } // end of foreach loop
}
```

I am able to read the response properly. The main issue is that I am not able to call the api with the 2nd value in the list.

Please let me know if I need to add more code for clarification.

Comment: Are you sure `Ids` contains id for both area code. You can add the logging in foreach loop to confirm what id is being iterated.

Comment: Possibly a deadlock. Are you blocking on an asynchronous operation somewhere?

Comment: @user1672994 yes, I am ```Ids``` are all the Ids for both area code. I had put a debugger on it.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The function ```GetAPIResponsePerID``` is just getting the response and bringing it back here .

Comment: Is it blocking or just skipping the second item and returns to caller of `ProcessIds`?

Comment: @Fildor For testing purpose I am just printing the response, and after it prints the response data of the first Id , it does nothing because I have not written the next part of the code.

Comment: @Fildor but ideally it should have gone to the next element and then print the response for it

Comment: That's clear. But does it _exit the loop and return_ or does it "hang" somewhere in the loop?

Comment: Finally after two hours of debugging I was able to fix this issue. There was a statement in my code segment handling the response that was causing a deadlock situation and the loop was not able to iterate further.